# Is null negative or positive?

Tags: c#, nullable

I know the `n.HasValue && n.Value > 0` but really curious to test null value, so:

```
decimal? n = null;
Console.Write(n>0); // false
Console.Write(n<0); // false
```

So is `null` object positive or negative in C# ?

Comment: Neither.  And the behavior you're seeing seems to demonstrate that.

Comment: neither as your test proves.

Comment: Try `Console.Write(n==0);` and be amazed...

Comment: @David : gotcha. Null is , like its name, nothing. `null == 0` ==> false, too.

Comment: @DioPhung: Numeric comparisons against something that isn't a number seem odd in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

`n > 0` compiles to `n.HasValue && n.Value > 0`, which produces false because `n.HasValue` returns false. Same for any other condtion, because `HasValue` always comes first.